# getting undefined reference error using snappy

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, snappy

I installed google snappy in my machine and the installation works fine

```
# make && make install
Scanning dependencies of target snappy
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-c.cc.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-sinksource.cc.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-stubs-internal.cc.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy.cc.o
[ 62%] Linking CXX static library libsnappy.a
[ 62%] Built target snappy
Scanning dependencies of target snappy_unittest
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy_unittest.dir/snappy_unittest.cc.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/snappy_unittest.dir/snappy-test.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable snappy_unittest
[100%] Built target snappy_unittest
[ 62%] Built target snappy
[100%] Built target snappy_unittest
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/libsnappy.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/snappy-c.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/snappy-sinksource.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/snappy.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/snappy-stubs-public.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/Snappy/SnappyTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/Snappy/SnappyTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/Snappy/SnappyConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/Snappy/SnappyConfigVersion.cmake
```

Then I write a simple cpp file to test the lib

```
# cat snappy-example.cpp 
#include <snappy.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string input = "Hello World";
  string output;
  snappy::Compress(input.data(), input.size(), &output);
  return 0;
}
```

when I run the compiling command, it returns an error: undefined reference

```
g++ -o example ./snappy-example.cpp -lsnappy
/tmp/cc5Y32Q3.o: In function `main':
snappy-example.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `snappy::Compress(char const*, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't figure out what's its problem. Can anyone help???

Comment: Try `-o` on the other side of your `cpp` files.

Comment: @Chipster Tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you figure this out ?